# Template parse errors: No provider for NgControl when creating custom form elements

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-elements

I've being trying to create custom elements with angular elements and for form inputs I've being trying to use angular's ControlValueAccessor for that as discussed in [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/reducing-the-forms-boilerplate-make-your-angular-forms-reusable-ee06d7c07f47) article by Eliran Eliassy.

But when I follow the guide, and completed the code - I ran into this problem.
**No provider for NgControl**. I have already imported FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule to app.module.ts file which is the remedy for this error (as normal). But it haven't fixed this time.

**[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhp2f9)**

What will be the problem? I attached the stackbliz above for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

Fixed the error by adding the ngDefaultControl as a directive in the custom element and implementing the part of the ControlValueAccessor manually.

Here is an example of implementation (Don't mind the validation part, not finished yet)
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elements-custom-input)

Please follow these issues for more information.

- [ngModelChange not fired and ngModel doesn't work for custom
  webcomponents (Angular
  Element](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29924)
- [@angular/elements usage with reactive formControls](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31351)
- [Template parse errors: No provider for NgControl when creating custom form elements With Angular Elements](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32315)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for posting here for more people get benefited from it.

You did 2 mistakes there:

1. When you injecting the `NgControl`, you don't have to provide the `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` token. the reason is `NgControl` is already providing the `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` token, and if you do it as well, you will run into a circular dependency issue.
2. Because your `TestComponent` is an entry component, you also have to add the `@Optional()` decorator before your `NgControl` injection. The reason is when you declaring a component in the entry component, angular compiles it factory even that it's not on the template, and because it's not part of any form and doesn't have any From directive on it, you will get this error of `No provider for NgControl`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello @Eliran, i tried them actually. Check the updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhp2f9) with the recommendations you mentioned. Now the previous error is gone, but introduced these two new ones.
```
Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'email'
``` 
And
```
TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
```
You can recreate them in the updated StackBlitz.
Thank you :)

Comment: Plus, when i'm trying your solution in my local environment - it gives the error ->

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'valueAccessor' of null** and 

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'email'**

Comment: Again, because not always your DI will get `NgControl`, of course, you can just add  `if` statement to check wheater you got it or not before you set the `valueAccessor` prop.

Comment: I tried that even @Eliran :/. That leads to **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'control' of null** which is actually the expected behaviour. So how can we rightfully inject the DI for NgControl if the one coming from the DI is null?

Comment: I see...and it makes sense if we thinking about it again.
So, I think that for that case, maybe getting the NgControl from the DI is not the best option. Need to find another way of doing it.

Comment: Yeah it seems so. I tried with the Injector (like injector.get(NgControl)) that also leads to static injection error. Have you got any idea on how the dependency must injected?

Comment: Hello @Eliran. According to this comment (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31351#issuecomment-508576239) we can implement the control valve accessor. How can we do that? You got any idea?

Comment: @KavindaJayakody Hey, I fell in the same issue - have you gotten any solution in you case?

Comment: @BrunoBruzzano i did found a solution, but not an elegant one i must say. Anyway it works and my custom element UI Kit is live in production now without problems. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57706681/6686446. I say again, not the elegant way

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your AppModule and DoBootstrap implementation. If you remove it and additionally remove your component from entryComponents in appModule and change how it is used at the app-component.html everything seems to work fine.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent, TestInputComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule  {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {

  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<form class="form-signin" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)" #f="ngForm" >
  <app-test-input [placeholder]="'Email'"
                          [isRequired]="true"
                          [errorMsg]="'Please enter your name'"
                          [label] = "'User Email'"
                          [pattern]="'[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+\\.[a-z]{2,3}'"
                          ngModel name="email"></app-test-input>

  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" [disabled]="!f.valid" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: No :/. That didn't fixed the issue. On the other hand, we shouldn't add NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR provider since NgControl already importing that (which may lead to cyclic dependency)

Comment: I have to use doBootstrap for creating the custom element from angular elements anyhow :/

Comment: Even in that example they have placed the custom-element-comp (testcomponent) in the entry components list (not in the declarations array). What to do about that?

Answer (score 0):

remove this line from your app.module.ts

```
entryComponents: [TestInputComponent]
```

also u have removed DoBootstrap implementation from app.module.ts
and replace ust-input with app-test-input and it will works.also remove

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: TestInputComponent,
      multi: true
    }]
```

because it's create cyclic dependency.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone else who get this Error, in my case the problem was a missing formControlName property and a missing formGroup as a parent. If you use custom form controls in your project as well, ensure all references -  formControlName's and [formGroup]="myFormGroup" - are set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Provide `NgControl` in your `TestingModule` like so:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ ... ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule ... ],
      declarations: [
        ...Component,
      ],
      providers: [NgControl], // <-- this
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(...Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```